# Know what appId is used in firebase authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have 3 web applications in my firebase project, dev, stg and prod. In my front end project, I configured it so that each environment uses an appId. I want to be able to know from which appId is the user authenticated. Is that possible ?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find this info in the `FirebaseApp` [`options`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/app.firebaseapp.md#firebaseappoptions) object which, among others, contains the `appId`.

For example with the JS SDK v9:

```
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
     console.log(auth.app.options.appId);
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @renaud for your reply. Is it possible to get it in firebase dashboard ?

Comment: You are welcome. What do you mean by "firebase dashboard"?

Comment: I mean the authentication dashboard in firebase, please see the image that I've added

Comment: No you cannot change the authentication dashboard offered by the Firebase console. I'm not sure what you mean by "getting it" in this dashboard, but, again you cannot modify it. If you need a dashboard, you'll have to build it yourself in your app.

Comment: I'm interested to get the appId from Firebase Dashboard, did you find the solution?

Comment: @CedricArnould Just click on the gear closed to the "Project Overview" menu item, and then "Project Settings"

Answer (score 1):

I know this might be late but it might help others still looking for an answer.

You can get your `appId` in the apps section under project settings

Open your firebase console and go to project settings from here ->

[image]

Under General, scroll down to your apps section and you'll find appids for each app of yours

[image]